корректность написания
корректно ли написать: провести проверку знаний учащемуся

корректно, но плохо звучит, лучше родительный падеж

Правильно: проверить знания учащегося (Р. п.).
Провести проверку — ненужный канцеляризм.
Или тогда: провести проверку знаний учащегося (Р. п.).
Пояснение
Смотрим словарь на портале Грамота.ру
ПРОВЕРИТЬ, -рю, -ришь; проверенный; -рен, -а, -о; св. КОГО-ЧТО или с придат. дополнит. 3. Подвергнуть испытанию для выяснения качеств, свойств, знаний, пригодности к чему-л. и т.п. П. мотор. П. работу механизма. П. на прочность кого-, что-л. П. ремень на сумке. П. новую методику обучения. П. молоко, мясо. П. знания учащихся. П. свои силы. П. себя. Проверять, -яю, -яешь; нсв. Проверяться, -яется; страд. Проверка (см.).
ЗНАНИЕ; ЗНАНЬЕ, -я; ср.  2. только мн.: знания, -ний. Совокупность сведений, познаний в какой-л. области человеческой деятельности; обладание сведениями о чём-л.
Знания инженера. Получить в школе прочные знания. Знания по архитектуре. Истинные знания существуют в виде законов науки. Знания в области математики. Совокупность знаний в области животноводства. Специалист с хорошими знаниями. 3. Владение навыками практических действий в каких-л. обстоятельствах, умение пользоваться чем-л. З. столярного ремесла. З. грамоты, языка. Практическое з. компьютера. Со знанием дела говорить, отвечать и т.п. (будучи хорошо осведомлённым, опытным в чём-л.).
